# Automatically Task Assignment by sql script

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below tables :

```
table person with fields :
id
name
city
email

table task with fields :
id
date
city
description


i have a bridge table ToDoList with feilds:

id
person_id
assignDate
assignTime
task_id
```

i need sql script to check below ifs and update ToDoList automatically after each update of task table:

find a person in person table has a same city with task? yes? check next if
if person in Todolist table has any assignment on todolist table on same date?

yes? check next if?

if this assignment time is longer than 1 hour ago in table for that person ? yes ? assign this person to task.

That would be if anybody has any idea on this problem to write an script ?

Best Regards

Comment: What did you try so far? Please include the relevant parts of your trials. Does it have to be plain sql? When will that routine be triggered, when a new task gets inserted? And what if more than one person matches your criteria?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, i am working on to write its trigger but i do not know how to write the IF section when it is checking more than 1 person with that 1 hour criteria ? do you have any thoughts?